# Adding Last Node to a Linked List

Tags: javascript, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am learning how to add node to the linked list. The following is the correct code:

```
class NodeList {
    constructor(head = null){
        this.head = head 
        this.addLast = function (data) {
            
            let node = new Node(data)
            console.log(curr)
        
            if (this.head === null) {
                return this.head = node
            } else{
                let curr = this.head
                while(curr.next){
                    curr = curr.next
                }
                curr.next = node
               
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Initially,

i wrote the code as such:

```
class NodeList {
    constructor(head = null){
        this.head = head 
        this.addLast = function (data) {

            let node = new Node(data)
            console.log(curr)

            if (this.head === null) {
                return this.head = node
            } else{
                let curr = this.head
                while(curr.next){
                    curr = curr.next
                }
                curr.next = node

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main difference is at the if statement. Instead of

```
if(this.head === null) { return this.head = node}
```

I wrote

```
let curr = this.head

if(curr  === null) { return curr  = node}
```

However, the code doesn't work.

If I do something like

let nodeList = new Nodelist
nodeList.addLast(2)

I expect to get head: Node {data: 2, next: null}. The first code achieved that purchase but the second code does not. I am confused why this is so. Both codes look the same. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Assigning to `curr` does not assign to `this.head`. JS is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference - you cannot assign to one property or variable and change another property or variable.

Comment: @trincot Ah thanks for the reminder! Sometimes the problem has been bugging at me for quite a few hours or days so I am excited to see the answers provided and get on with my practice without remembering to mark as answered. Will mark answers as accepted next time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can read the linked-list source code from here https://github.com/samavati/tsds

Answer (score 0):

The difference is this:

`curr` is a variable. `this.head` is a property of an object.

If you assign to `curr` you will see the effect when looking at the variable, nowhere else. If you assign to `this.head` you modify the property that belongs to an object. So this *mutates* an object. The assignment to `curr` *cannot* mutate an object. It just assigns something to a variable.

*If* assigning to a variable would mutate an object (and in this case the *list*), then imagine what havoc the statement `curr = curr.next` would bring (in the `else` block)... Yet, you do seem to understand that this statement does not change the list, it merely allows to walk along that list with a variable. There is no reason to then think that `curr = node` would alter the list.

It may help to visualise the procedure in the first code block. Let's say we call `addLast(1)` on a list that is empty. When we arrive in the `if` block we could picture the state like this:

```
 this                  node
  │                     │
  ▼                     ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: null │    │ val: 1     │
└────────────┘    │ next: None │
                  └────────────┘
```

So we essentially have two variables at this point: `this` and `node`. Then `curr = this.head` is executed:

```
 this curr             node
  │    │                │
  ▼    ▼                ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: null │    │ val: 1     │
└────────────┘    │ next: None │
                  └────────────┘
```

Then your code suggest doing `curr = node`. Look what happens:

```
 this curr             node
  │    └────────────┐   │
  ▼                 ▼   ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: null │    │ val: 1     │
└────────────┘    │ next: None │
                  └────────────┘
```

If instead you'd do `curr.next = node`, you get the *mutation* you need:

```
 this curr             node
  │    │                │
  ▼    ▼                ▼
┌────────────┐    ┌────────────┐
│ head: ────────► │ val: 1     │
└────────────┘    │ next: None │
                  └────────────┘
```

Hope this clarifies it.